# Show SQL query results in HTML textboxes

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I've created a database table named `users` and I created a php file named `forms.php`. `forms.php` has 2 forms. The first form is to search, and the second form is the records from the database should appear:

```
               <form method="post" action="search.php">
                    <div class="input-group has-success">
                        <input id="btn-input" name="search" type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Please type the ID number of the user you want to update..." />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="btn-chat" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <form role="form">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>username</label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Placeholder">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input class="form-control">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>UserType</label>
                                <input class="form-control">
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

And this the php script for search in the first form. this is the script in my **search.php**:

```
          <?php

            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "asset_inventory");

         if($conn === false){
              die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
         }


         $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);


         $sql = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE user_id='$search'";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

         $id=$row['user_id']; 
         $name=$row['user_name']; 
         $pass=$row['user_pass']; 
         $type=$row['user_type'];

         header("location: forms.php");
    }

      } else {
         echo "0 results";
   }


     mysqli_close($conn);
       ?>
```

Now I want to use the variables mentioned in `search.php` that contain the rows to be displayed in the 2nd form in the header `forms.php`. Any suggestions? I'm stuck at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Submit the form to the same forms.php and handle printing the results from the search inside your document, simply iterate over the results and print the desired html
2. You can use AJAX and send a request to search.php with a search query and return a JSON results and then with some javascript code in forms.php to render the results.

Comment: so i wont be needing the search.php 

instead ill just put the script in forms.php?

Comment: Yes, basically you can handle a form in the same page, get the results and print them if you recieved a post/get param.

The second option requires a second php file that just receive a param, gets the data and returns it in a JSON format so the javascript handles it.

Comment: thank you for ur advice.. I know how to make a json file from my search.php querry, but i dont know how to display or echo it on a textbox.. please if u know.. i mean the json file arrays

Comment: Okay i get it, ill just transfer the querry from search.php and put it in forms.php. and to display, ill just echo it in the input boxes.. thanks u! :)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to keep my explanation/solution as simple as possible since your code suggests you are just beginning with this stuff.

You wrote search.php to return data from the database. It does a good job at that. The problem is that once you have the data, you're not doing anything with it. I'm talking about these line of codes:

```
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      $name=$row['user_name']; 
      $pass=$row['user_pass']; 
      $type=$row['user_type'];
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "0 results";
  }
```

So you are setting the $name, $pass and $type variables, and this is the data you need. If it finds a second user, it overwrites the $name, $pass and $type variables, and your first user data disappears from PHP (it stays in the database though, no worries).

An easy to understand solution would be to change the place of the code. You should show the data while you're in the while()-loop. So if you put the while()-loop code in your HTML page, you could make a table showing the user info like this:

```
<table>

<?php
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

?>

  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $name=$row['user_name']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $name=$row['user_pass']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $name=$row['user_type']; ?> </td>
  </tr>

<?php
    }
  }
  else
  {
?>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">0 results</td>
  </tr>

<?php
  }
?>

</table>
```

Other solutions include functions and classes, but your code suggests you don't know about them yet. I suggest you try to build your page with the knowledge you already have. Then read about functions. Then rebuild the same page but create a function for it.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. What i want to do is to pass the data on those variables from search.php to the 2nd form of my forms.php

ill be using the 2nd form in forms.php to execute an update to database..

Comment: i just need to call those variables from search.php to input boxes in the 2nd form of forms.php

Comment: I added a header location.. lastly is how to call those variables and display it in input boxes.. by the way ill be using it for an update querry

Comment: Like I said: other solutions include functions and classes. What you describe is a function. Look how to create a function and put the database-query in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ajax approach. simple and convenient

**THE FORM PAGE**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>         
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "#btn-chat", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        //Built a url to send
        var info = $("#form").serialize();                          
        $.ajax({     
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: info,
            success: function(result){                  
                  //$('#respoondarea').load(location.href + '#respondarea');                
                  //$("#form")[0].reset();
                  $('#respond').html(result);   
            }
        });     
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 
});

</script>             
               <form method="post" id="form" action="search.php">
                    <div class="input-group has-success">
                        <input id="btn-input" name="search" type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Please type the ID number of the user you want to update..." />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="btn-chat" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>

<div id="respond"></div>
```

**THE SEARCH PHP PAGE**

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "asset_inventory");
if($conn === false){
       die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$search = $_POST['search'];
//$query_user = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM  users WHERE user_id='$search'");
$query_user = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM  users WHERE user_id LIKE '%$search%' ");
$row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_user);
$totalRows_user = mysqli_num_rows($query_user);

?>

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th><th>User pass</th><th>User type</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <?php  do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_user['user_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_user['user_pass']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_user['user_type']; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php } while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_user));   ?> 
    </tbody>
  </table>

 <?php if ($totalRows_user == 0) { // Show if record empty ?>

 <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"> No record found </div>

 <?php } // Show if recordset empty ?>
```

HOPE IT HELPS